# Angular 2/Webpack Environment Configurations

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-2

I would like to configure my Webpack build such that I can declare `import { environment } from './environments/environment'` in my Angular 2 components and have the import load `environment.ts` during development, but `environment.prod.ts` in production. How would I tell Webpack to replace the import during a build?

I'm looking for something very similar to the way projects created with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) are handling environment configurations. Unfortunately, I'd rather not use the CLI yet as it is still in beta, and I also haven't wrapped my head around how the project works and how to extend its build pipe.

I also want to avoid scattering conditional statements throughout my source code, so no using `process.env.NODE_ENV` in an if-statement everywhere that I want to import the environment file.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that you were NOT using Angular CLI... You tell webpack to use `environment.prod.ts` during the build with `ng build --env=prod`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out a way to do this. First, the environment files:

environment.interface.ts:

```
export interface Environment {
    apiRoot: string,
    target: string
}
```

environment.dev.ts:

```
import { Environment } from './environment.interface';

export const environment: Environment = {
    target: 'dev',
    apiRoot: 'http://www.dev.api.com'
}
```

environment.prod.ts:

```
import { Environment } from './environment.interface';

export const environment: Environment = {
    target: 'prod',
    apiRoot: 'http://www.api.com'
}
```

environment.ts:

```
export { environment } from './environment.dev';
```

Then, import into the Angular components as normal:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

Finally, using the NormalModuleReplacementPlugin in the webpack configuration:

webpack.prod.js:

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\.\/environment\.dev/, './environment.prod')
  ]
});
```

The first parameter in the NormalModuleReplacementPlugin is a Regex that matches `environment.dev` in `environment.ts`. The second parameter is the configuration module that you want to use in the build.

I'm sure that this could be made a bit more elegant by using some environment variables, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: how are you passing in the enviornment on your build command?  like this:--env=prod

Comment: I believe I was using Webpack's --config option from the package.json:

`"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --env.APP_TARGET prod --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile"`

`"build:dev": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile"`